# angular 6 Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to import `HttpHeaders` but when I import it I get this error :

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'HttpHeaders' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

I import this :

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

into my `app.module.ts` and into `my service.ts`

and I import this :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PremierComComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpHeaders,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

in the `app.module.ts`

Can someone explain me how to solve the error?

Comment: The `imports` array is for importing modules, such as the `HttpClientModule` above. It can only contain modules, but `HttpHeaders` is not a module

Comment: HttpHeaders should be imported just in the service that use it. Inject Http and add, in the function, the custom headers.

Answer (score 3):

The `HttpHeaders` are a class. The only thing which should be in your imports is an array of modules which are always decorated with the `@NgModule` tag. So you should remove the `HttpHeaders` from the imports array.

Sources:

- [Angular HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)
- [Angular Http](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule)